# Create multiple files dynamically nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to download all files in database as zip file.

If I want to download only element, I can easily set its header and content type, and then can send its buffer.

```
db.collection("resource").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
 res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + result[0].name);
 res.contentType(result[0].mimetype);
 res.send(result[0].data.buffer);
}
```

Now I want to create a folder and add the each `result` element to this folder then send it.

The following code just returns the first file. It's rational because immediatly I send the buffer.

```
for(var i=0; i < result.length; i++){
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + result[i].name);
  res.send(result[i].data.buffer);
}
```

I think about adding them into an array.

```
for(var i=0; i < result.length; i++){
  var obj = {name: result[i].name, buffer: result[i].data.buffer};
  files.push(obj);
}


res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + "resource");
res.contentType('application/zip');
res.send(files);
```

This returned me a text file `resource` which includes `name` and `buffer` as JSON format.

Even if I update the contentType as  application/zip it returns as text fomat.

How can I create this files, add into a folder and set the folder type as zip?

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet is a simplified version of a code that works for me. I had to remove my wrappers, so that it is easier to understand so this might have result into something being buggy.

```
    function bundleFilesToZip(fileUrls, next) {
      // step 1) use node's fs library to copy the files u want
      //         to massively download into a new folder


      //@TODO: HERE create a directory
      // out of your fileUrls array at location: folderUri

      // step 2) use the tarfs npm module to create a zip file out of that folder

      var zipUri = folderUri+'.zip';
      var stream = tarfs.pack(folderUri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(zipUri));
      stream.on('finish', function () {
        next(null, zipUri);
      });
      stream.on('error', function (err) {
        next(err);
      });
    }

    // step 3) call the function u created with the files u wish to be downloaded

    bundleFilesToZip(['file/uri/1', 'file/uri/2'], function(err, zipUri) {
     res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=moustokoulouro');
     // step 4) pipe a read stream from that zip to the response with
     //         node's fs library
     fs.createReadStream(zipUri).pipe(res);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use the `res.attachment([filename])` from official Express API, (http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Also you can use the `adm-zip` module for creating the zip folder
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip)